# How do I change the language in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, settings, multilingual

We use the list filter in jquery mobile:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
...
```

So, this creates an input field with the following placeholder text in it "Filter items...":
[image]

**Where or how can I change the language/text of this field?**

I looked in the [global configuration](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html), but did not find any clue...

Comment: Can you show your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ? As for me it is just a placeholder which could be changed to what ever you want

Comment: I have found some attribute in the link you provided, try to add `data-filter-placeholder="Some string"`

Comment: @Pavlo Thank you! This is the solution. If you post it as an official answer, I will mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, just adding an extra attribut (which can be translated with php):

```
<...data-filter-placeholder="Some string"...>
```

Answered originally by [Pavlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506147/pavlo) as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on document ready

```
$("input[placeholder='Filter items...']").attr("placeholder", "Search...");
```

This will just find all inputs elements with "Filter items..." & will Replace that text with "Search...".

Comment: This is an unwanted workaround. I want a sound solution.